# Why is jetpack compose preview taking minutes to load?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Using Jetpack Compose and the layout preview for a composable is taking over a minute to load, does this sound like an issue with my Android Studio or a compose issue?

Comment: Does it take minutes to build the app? Previews require an up-to-date build of the app, so if a build takes minutes, the preview will take minutes.

Comment: It's curious how the [documentation about Preview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling) doesn't mention anything about the successful build requirement.

Comment: No the build is relatively quick maybe around 30 seconds max, the preview build is extremely bad at times though as it constantly refuses to display changes then just randomly does it

Comment: I'm working on a big project which take normally 5 minutes (without jetpack) to build using macbook pro 2019 16gb/2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
It's really frustrating just to see preview I have to wait for more than 5 minutes on everychange.

Answer (score 0):

Preview speeds are much faster with the latest bumblebee update of studio Canary. Also, configure your antivirus to skip build files from real-time scanning since it dramatically slows down builds.

Comment: Nope, still no. I think its overmarketed. Any change requires rebuild to see the result. Mby because I've seen Flutter's hot reload

Answer (score 0):

I had really great preview times (~1s) and then out of nowhere it started taking up to 3 minutes to load previews and previewing them incorrectly. Invalidating the caches and restarting Android Studio seemed to do the trick for me.